# From Microsoft Query

Tags: sql, excel

I am using From Microsoft Query and just couldn't resolve how to fix this issue.  I am trying to use parameters H5 and I5 (Date) but don't know whats going on, would be good if someone can look into this for me.

```
SELECT `Sheet1$`.Name, `Sheet1$`.Phone, `Sheet1$`.DateTime
FROM `C:\Users\ABC\Downloads\Jan19.xlsx`.`Sheet1$` `Sheet1$`
WHERE `Sheet1$`.DateTime BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Thank you

Comment: SELECT Sheet1$.Name, Sheet1$.Phone, Sheet1$.DateTime FROM C:\Users\ABC\Downloads\Jan19.xlsx.Sheet1$ Sheet1$ WHERE Sheet1$.DateTime #21/01/2019# work fine but I am trying to use parameter and not working :(

Comment: Back-ticks and Excel, does that work?

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is a data type in SQL language, it may got confused by recognizing it as a column or a data type, try this

> `Sheet1$`.[DateTime]

Comment: I changed it to WHERE `Sheet1$`.[EventTime] BETWEEN ? AND ? but still same error Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: @HassanArshad Would you mind showing me the error message? it sounds like you have a data type issue in your code, whether your EventTime column didn't configure as a datetime/time date type, or you forget to add a quote in the time you put in filter. e.g. between '2019/1/1' and ''2019/1/2'